# How to get the orientation type when capturing image via Intent?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am stuck with a problem, when capturing image via intent.

I am using the default intent code for capturing image. as follows.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                 startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
```

and receiving it in onActivityResult as follow.

```
  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if( TAKE_PHOTO_CODE==requestCode){

        try {
             Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
             Bitmap mImageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
             selectedImagePath = saveImageInfo(mImageBitmap, "image");
             ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(selectedImagePath);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext()," "+exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         try {
                showDialog(DIALOG_UPLOADING);

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          } catch (Exception e) {

          e.printStackTrace();
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No image selected.. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

I want the captured image orientation in this onActivityResult method, i have search and about it and found the ExifInterface, but it does not work for me, I am testing on LG Optimus Android device, it always returns 0 for me.

The problem is after capturing image it is rotated. 
Any Solution?

Comment: why don't you try to compare the `height`and its `width`? if `h>=w` then *portrait* else *landscape*?

Comment: comparing height and width will create problems...Test it on nexus 1 and nexus S , u'll see the problems...

Answer (score 1):

You can get the rotation by using the method and then rotate the image according to the result -

```
private int getDisplayRotation() {
    int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0: return 0;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90: return 90;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180: return 180;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270: return 270;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

to get rid of lots of device specific problems, I created camera from scratch
You can get the code from https://github.com/vinsol/expense-tracker/tree/master/src/com/vinsol/expensetracker/cameraservice

and then call it using the following method

```
private void startCamera() {
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        Intent camera = new Intent(this, Camera.class);
        File file = new File("123.jpg");
        Log.d("camera file path "+file.toString() );
        camera.putExtra("FullSizeImagePath", file.toString());
        startActivityForResult(camera, PICTURE_RESULT);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "sdcard not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, getDisplayRotation() always returning 0 in all case. Also i don't want to implement open camera via class. is there any inbuilt method? by which we can get its orientation.

Comment: it will return according to orientation and the orientation in your layout files...if you test it in a tablet this will return 90...u can test the camera from https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vinsol.expensetracker, it is the same method as used by google(i used camera 2.2 and 4.0 code and merge the code to make the camera like this)